# What are the odds of 2 people getting the same answer 6 times on 6 different Buzzfeed quizzes?

Tags: probability

I watched a video on youtube where 2 people got the same answer as each other on 6 different Buzzfeed Quizzes, and nobody in the comments or in the video found the odds. Since i lack any knowledge on how math works, i came to my favorite site for answers on math, made an account for once, and typed this question. please help me on this, its gonna bug me forever.

Edit: The Youtuber who did these quizzes was Twobold, and this is the link to the video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCr73r3CSTM

Comment: What have you tried working out so far? People will be more inclined to answer a question that shows effort towards a solution, and states what is the tricky part in finding a full solution. Also, I think more information is necessary to answer this question. Such as, how may questions are on each buzz feed quiz?

Comment: It matters what kind of questions and who is answering them. If the question is something like "how much is $5-3$" or "do you enjoy hammering nails into your feet" you will tend to get the same answer from two different people.